# What configuration setting(s) fixes the "enableCaseSwarming" deployment error?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, case

I'm getting the following error from the metadata API when trying to do a deployment:

| Type | Name | Problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Error | Case | enableCaseSwarming |

Curiously, `enableCaseSwarming` does not return a great answer when I search for it, though I can recognize this error is likely caused by something in the Case or Support settings. Does anyone know what setting or combination of settings resolves this error?

**Edit**: I've identified a setting on [CaseSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_casesettings.htm) called this, but it's undocumented on the page in the metadata API documentation. My best guess is that this setting is only available in certain types of orgs to toggle the "[Swarm on a Case to Resolve Customer Issues (Beta)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_swarming_on_a_case.htm&type=5&release=236)" setting.

Comment: What metadata are you deploying? Is the target org a scratch org? Using SFDX?

Comment: This was caused by deploying `Case.settings-meta.xml` to a target org using SFDX. Both the source and target were on API version 55 (Summer 22). I was able to resolve the issue by removing `<enableCaseSwarming>false</enableCaseSwarming>` from the Case metadata. My assumption is the source org is eligible for this feature, but the target was not. So the reference was causing issues being in there even though it wasn't enabled.